# Legend on ggplot2 with 3 graphs (on the x-axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to create a legend for the following 3 graphs on the x-axis? Thanks for your help!

```
library("ggplot2")

theme_set(theme_bw())# White background for plots

#creating 3 X 4 data frame (reduced from 50 x4 for 50 states)
state_name = as.factor(c("State_A","State_B","State_C"))

mw = c(7.25,11.5,7.25)
mw_tip = c(2.13,2.63,5.50)
mw_gap = mw-mw_tip
wage_data = data.frame(state_name,mw,mw_tip,mw_gap)

wage_data
str(wage_data)

#Re-order the df according to mw, mw_tip, mw_gap, 
#therefore, states won'd be listed alphabetically
#below, #ordering by mw, mw_tip, and gap

wage_data = wage_data[order(wage_data$mw,wage_data$mw_tip,wage_data$mw_gap),]
wage_data$state_name=factor(wage_data$state_name, as.character(unique(wage_data$state_name)))
wage_data #now ordered as State_A, State_C, State B that is plotted below

#Below, I plot 3 graphs: mw, mw_tip, mw_gap on the x-axis
(fig=ggplot(wage_data,aes(y=state_name,x=mw)))
(fig=fig+labs(x="Dollars per hour",y="50 U.S. States"))
(fig=fig+geom_point(size=3,color="green"))
(fig=fig+geom_point(aes(x=mw_tip),size=3,color="red",shape=17))
(fig=fig+geom_point(aes(x=mw_gap),size=3,color="orange",shape=15))
(fig=fig+scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,11.5,0.5)))

#Below, legend does not work! I also tried with scale... 
#and with aes, nothing worked for me
(fig=fig+theme(legend.position = c(0.9,0.15),legend.justification = c(1,0), legend.title = element_blank()))
#End of code
```

**Plots that needs a legend**

[image]

Comment: I see your point now: fig = ggplot(xxx) instead of fig=ggplot(xxx), thanks!

Comment: What I meant was that adding spacing between operators is almost always a good idea (unless you're code golfing) and helps with readability. See e.g. [Google's R style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml). That aside, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to avoid the different calls to `goem_point` for every column; instead you can reshape your data from wide to long prior to plotting, and use the `what` key as a colour aesthetic. This automatically introduces a corresponding legend.

```
state_name <- factor(c("State_A", "State_B", "State_C"))
mw <- c(7.25, 11.5, 7.25)
mw_tip <- c(2.13, 2.63, 5.50)
mw_gap <- mw - mw_tip
wage_data <- data.frame(state_name, mw, mw_tip, mw_gap)

library(tidyverse);
wage_data %>%
    gather(what, value, -state_name) %>%
    ggplot(aes(value, state_name, colour = what, group = what)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Or using `geom_point` with different symbols:

```
wage_data %>%
    gather(what, value, -state_name) %>%
    ggplot(aes(value, state_name, colour = what, shape = what)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution works! 
Initially, I was worried that changing from Wide to Long may change the factor levels, because in your graph, "mw" was not ordered from low to high. However, I just tested your solution on the my ordered data frame, and it seems that the order was preserved.

Comment: @user9613312 You can always reorder factor levels after reshaping as well if necessary. Please consider closing the question by setting the check mark next to the solution.